# How to group multi-year expenses by month and get moving average?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-dates

I have an Excel sheet with a table of different types of expenses spanning over several years. Data is still being added to the table.

| Date | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-02 | TypeA | 30 |
| 2023-06-08 | TypeB | 50 |

I want to have monthly expenses and moving average of last 12 months of certain types of expenses.

I tried creating a Pivot table and grouping by month, but I get all data grouped to 12 months, not to X years * 12 months. So I cant add a moving average column.

How do I do it?

Comment: Can you please add few more data and then show your desired output also?

Comment: You can create an additional column `=YEAR(A2)&TEXT(MONTH(A2),"00") and use it in the pivot table

Comment: I will try this workaround. It basically creates additional filter for each row, like 2023JAN, 2024JAN, 2024Feb and etc. to be used in Pivot table as grouping element